# jQuery Smooth Div Scroll - Right Hotspot not activating

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, smoothing

I'm having an issue where the right hotspot on does not seem to be activating on mouse over. The left seems to work fine though. http://christophermoulder.alykee.com/lighting/

Here's the code I'm using as well as the css:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({ 
        mousewheelScrolling: true,
        visibleHotSpotBackgrounds: 'onstart',
        hotSpotsVisibleTime:5000,
        hotSpotScrollingStep:2,
        hotSpotScrollingInterval:1,
        autoScrollingMode: "",
        autoScrollingDirection: "endlessloopright",
        manualContinuousScrolling: true
    });
});
```

Does anything jump out that might be causing this problem?

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: it is working fine for me here..i jus checked ur link

Answer (score 1):

So, you need some (exactly two) CSS Styles to solve your problem:

First, the "makeMeScrollable" Container must be have relative position:

```
div#makeMeScrollable {
position: relative;
}
```

Now, set the right-position from the "scrollingHotSpotRight" to 0:

```
div.scrollingHotSpotRight {
right: 0;
}
```

That's all.

PS: I had the same Problem. ;)